# How do i sort a class to match specific characteristics

Tags: python, database, class, sorting, project

So,Basically im new to python and coding overall.Starting to build my first project.I learned some courses for OOP but i need some help.
My idea for a project is to show specific kind of mushrooms based on the user input like cap color,gills color,habitat and etc.
Do i work with classes or i need to start learning database.How exacly i am able to accomplish my goal.
An example of this will be
Input is:Yellow,white,forest
Output need to be list of mushrooms that have the same characteristics.
I know how do classes work but i seem to be hitting a wall here

Comment: start with studying Pandas dataframes.

Comment: Where will you get your data from? It's impossible to answer without that and more info. You could use a database.. or a text file, or simply an array you copy/paste into your code. You need to provide more information and your question needs to be more focused.

Comment: I get all the data for a very famous mushrooms site.I made a class named Mushroom.And then i copy and paste each name and give it the specifications (color,habitat,gills,etc.)The process is slow but i think its worth it.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use dictionaries as well as read the documentation of dictionaries and lists in python, but here is an idea:

```
mushrooms_college = {'name':['Ganoderma lucidum','Amanita phalloides'],'color':['red and yellow', 'red and black']}

color_mushroom = input('what is the color? ')

values_colors_mushrooms = list(mushrooms_college['color'])

index = values_colors_mushrooms .index(color_mushroom)

mushrooms_college['name'][index]
```